# HTML variable in string?

Tags: php

When I use this code:

```
    $message = "Transaction ID: " . echo $transid . "\n\nURL: " . echo $url . "\n\nAnchor Text: " . echo $anchortext . "\n\nEmail: " . echo $email;
```

I get this error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ECHO in [file location] on line 35

Line 35 is that above line of code.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you're trying to "build" your string, you don't need the `echo` statements.

For instance, you concatenate strings like this:

```
$str = "first part" . "second part";
```

or

```
$str = "first part" . $someVariable;
```

In your case, you would simply do:

```
$message = "Transaction ID: " . $transid . "\n\nURL: " . $url . "\n\nAnchor Text: " . $anchortext . "\n\nEmail: " . $email;
```

Answer (score 1):

Double quoted strings allow to interpolate variables:

```
$message = "Transaction ID: $transid\n\nURL: $url\n\nAnchor Text: $anchortext\n\nEmail: $email";
```

That's the one feature that separates scripting languages from static languages. Utilize it.

See also [What is the difference between single-quoted and double-quoted strings in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3446216/difference-between-single-quote-and-double-quote-string-in-php) (in particlar "[heredoc](http://php.net/heredoc)" strings).

Answer (score 0):

```
$message = "Transaction ID: " . $transid . "\n\nURL: " . $url . "\n\nAnchor Text: " . $anchortext . "\n\nEmail: " . $email;
```

this should work for you.

Now just use `$message` variable to echo you message.

**EDIT**

the problem to getting the error because you are using the `echo` into your string that was :

```
$message = "Transaction ID: " . echo $transid . "\n\nURL: " . echo $url . "\n\nAnchor Text: " . echo $anchortext . "\n\nEmail: " . echo $email;
```

Comment: This does not provide any explanation of what was wrong with his original code.